# getNodeName() not getting Node Name

Tags: java, android, xpath, xml-parsing

i am getting names and values of nodes from an xml using XPath but the code i am trying is not getting me node names ...
here is the xml i am parsing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <reg>
  <user>
    <Name>adil</Name>
    <Email>adil@gmail.com</Email>
    <Picture>/storage/sdcard0/DCIM/browser-photos/1352975129941.jpg</Picture>
    <LastEdited>26 Mar 2014 11:49:39</LastEdited>
  </user>
<user>
<Name>zeeshan</Name>
<Email>zajmal@gmail.con</Email>
<Picture>/storage/sdcard0/DCIM/browser-photos/1352975129941.jpg</Picture>
<LastEdited>26 Mar 2014 11:49:39</LastEdited>
</user>
</reg>
```

Here is the code i am trying

```
XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    String expression = "//Email[text()='"adil@gmail.com"']";
    System.out.println(expression);
    Node node = (Node) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODE);
        if(null != node) {
        Node pNode = node.getParentNode();
        nodeList = pNode.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0;null!=nodeList && i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node nod = nodeList.item(i);
        if(nod.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
               {         
System.out.println(nod.getFirstChild().getNodeName().toString() + " : " + nod.getFirstChild().getNodeValue()); 
}
```

the output of `system.out.println()` is

```
#text : adil
#text : adil@gmail.com 
#text : /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/browser-photos/1352975129941.jpg
#text : 26 Mar 2014 11:49:39
```

i am not being able to pick the point where i am wrong...

Comment: Did you try printing the parent node names as well? AFAIK the text between two tags is a node as well, i.e. `<Name>adil</Name>` would be two nodes: `Name` and `text` (an unnamed text node). What I mean is: instead of `nod.getFirstChild().getNodeName()` try `nod.getNodeName()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function

```
     public List<List<String>> Parseyourxmls(String xml) {

                List<List<String>> ll = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
                try {
                    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                            .newInstance();
                    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is);
                    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

                    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("OrderDetails");

                    if (nList.getLength() > 0) {
                        Node nNode = nList.item(0);
                        for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {

                            nNode = nList.item(i);

                            System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :"
                                    + nNode.getNodeName());

                            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                                List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
                                l.add(0, eElement.getElementsByTagName("Name")
                                        .item(0).getTextContent());
                                l.add(1, eElement.getElementsByTagName("Email")
                                        .item(0).getTextContent());
/*all other */
                                ll.add(l);
                            }

                        }
                        return ll;
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("11111", e.toString());
                }
                return ll;

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are iterating through the node list with

```
for (int i = 0; null != nodeList && i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
    Node nod = nodeList.item(i);
    // ...
}
```

Each time you get the current child node of the user node with the `nodeList.item(i)` call, that is you get the name node first, then the email node, and so on. But then you are printing out

```
System.out.println(nod.getFirstChild().getNodeName().toString()  + ...)
```

Here, you are retrieving the first child of the current node. The first child node of the name node is the text node containing the content. The same is true for all other nodes. A text node does not have a recognizable name. The "#text" output just tells you, that is a text node.

Waht you want is to print out the node's name. Like that:

```
System.out.println(nod.getNodeName().toString()  + ...)
```